# Variable into style attr Jquery

Tags: jquery

I declare a variable called url_cover

```
var url_cover = "images/picture1.png";
```

I want to put this variable into an attr function like this :

```
$('.top-profile').attr('style','background: url("'url_cover'")');
```

It does not work and I don't know why

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to concatenate in js you need + sign

```
'+ variablehere +'
```

you can use `.css()`  instead of change `attr('style')`

```
$('.top-profile').css('background' , 'url("'+url_cover+'")');
```

> sorry for my old answer I just said use dot to concatenate in js but I
>   was confused cause I working with php as well  and dot to
>   concatenate in php   but  + for concatenate in js

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) :

Easy way of Concatenation :

```
var url_cover = "images/picture1.png";

$('.top-profile').css({ 
    'background':'url('+url_cover+')'
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CXDu7/15/)